# NavigationController with a UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I'm training to develop an application without using any graphical interface manually. for this, I am using Quartz 2D framework. In my case I created a custom view (UIView) and added it to my UIWindow in AppDelegate.m file:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    ViewCustom *view = [[ViewCustom alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height)];

    [self.window addSubview:view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**ViewCustom.m**

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
   //Draw code comes here
}
```

All i'm trying to do is create a navigation controller inside AppDelegate or inside my Custom View (what way is better?), I try to use this code below:

```
UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view];
```

But he say that **is incompatible UIView with an UIViewController**, how I solve this problem, and add an navigationController in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initWithRootViewController` accepts, as the error message reports, an `UIViewController`. The view you are trying to add is a `UIView`.

Try creating instead a `UIViewController` and set your `view` as the `view` of this controller.

Ex:

```
ViewCustom *customView = [[ViewCustom alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height)];

UIViewController *myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
myViewController.view = customView;
```

Then:

```
UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myController];
```

Comment: Your code works very, well, but I have one question.. how I can add a title for this NavigationController?

Comment: @user3781174 You could set the `title` of your controller before you add it to the navigation controller: `myViewController.title = @"my title";`.

Answer (score 1):

The method `initWithRootViewController` of `UINavigationController` expects a `UIViewController` instance as parameter, so instead of passing view, wrap it with a `UIViewContrller` like this:

```
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
//The view of this controller will be instance of your CustomView.
controller.view = view; 

//Add UIViewController to navigation controller as root.
UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

//now add navigation as root.
[self.window addRootViewController:navigation];
```

I was wondering how do you not consider the `UINavigationController` as native GUI component and using it in your app, as you yourself said:

> I'm training to develop an application without using any graphical
>   interface manually.